# How to pass parameter to text output in Vue.js 2.x

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this file containing translations to be used in my game application:

```js
{
  "de": {
    "gamestate": {
      "won": "Gewonnen!",
      "lost": "Leider verloren!",
      "retry": "Nochmal versuchen"
    },
    "settings": {
      "label": {
        "playfieldWidth": "Spielfeldbreite",
        "playfieldHeight": "Spielfeldhöhe",
        "fieldSize": "Feldbreite",
        "bombcount": "Anzahl der Bomben"
      }
    }
  },
  "en": {
    "gamestate": {
      "won": "You won!",
      "lost": "Game over!",
      "retry": "Retry"
    },
    "settings": {
      "label": {
        "playfieldWidth": "playfield width",
        "playfieldHeight": "playfield height",
        "fieldSize": "field size",
        "bombcount": "Number of bombs"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I put these in a `const messages = require('/i18n/translations.json')` and attach it to my `data` property.

In my VM, I have a data property that contains the iso code for the language:

```js
data () { 
  return { 
    language: 'en',
    messages
  }
}
```

Now when I want to output messages from this, I'd like to go

```js
<p>{{ message('gamestate.won') }}</p>
```

For this purpose I wrote a computed:

```js
computed: {
  message (key) {
    let message = messages[this.language]
    key.split('.').forEach(function (keypart) {
      message = message.hasOwnProperty(keypart) ? message[keypart] : undefined
    })
    return message || key
  }
}
```

But unfortunately `computed` properties don't seem to take arguments, and that's why I get

```js
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: key.split is not a function"
```

Next I tried to implement as a `methods` property instead of a `computed`, which changes the error to

```js
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.message is not a function"
```

How can I achieve my goal using Vue.js 2x?

Comment: Could you post your `methods` approach too?

Comment: It's identical.

Comment: Seems to work. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/OzOGYP?editors=1010

Comment: Found the problem, which was that old code was still in effect. Thanks for the quick help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

As someone proved via a codepen, my code works. The problem was that before I implemented the translation stuff, I was already using a property `message` which my `endGame()` method was trying to fill:

```
endGame () {
  this.winLoseSymbol = ''
  this.message = 'GAME OVER!' // this was the cause of the problem
  this.gamestate = 'lost' 
  this.stopTimer()
}
```

Since in the new version message is supposed to be a function, overwriting it with a string causes those parts of the application that were using the function to fail.